# How to setOnTouchListener to overlap child?

Tags: android

I have create program like this:

[image]

Gray shape child of green shape and green shape child of megneta shape i set ClipChildren to false to show child(gray shape) over parent. I can get OnTouchListener from gray shape but OnTochListener not work on part of gray shape out of parent(green)

How can i do this?

Comment: can you show your xml?

Comment: i create this programmitically

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Bitmap then it's very easy to do, just get the colour code of the selected pixel by

`int currentColour = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);`

Here x and y are the current pointer location, you will receive in onTouch callback.

then match the colour and process if it matched.

Comment: this is not real this program example all of shapes are View(RelativeLayout or Framelayout)

Comment: Then best way to implement touch listener to the view on which you want to listen the onTouch :)

Comment: gray view is child of green view touchListener not work on part of view(gray) that out of parent view

Answer (score 0):

The touch event order is : parent--->child. if you touch out of the green,then green can't get touch event so it cannot pass the event to its child